# Discord py - react to a message with cooldown (on_message)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want to add a feature to my discord bot, where it reacts to a specific message like `"react to me"`. But only once in 5 minutes. How can I make a cooldown for that in the `on_message` event?

Example:

```
Today, 15:00 - User#0001: React to me, bot
-- BOT REACTS TO MESSAGE
Today, 15:01 - User#0001: React to me!!
-- BOT DOESNT REACT, CAUSE OF COOLDOWN
Today, 15:06 - User#0001: React to me
-- BOT REACTS TO MESSAGE
```

I hope it's understandable what I need.
If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what is the purpose of this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to know how it works, to learn cooldowns in discord py, and to use it on other things.

Comment: I tried nothing Lukas because I can't find a way to do it for that, what I want.

Comment: PS: If you haven't tried anything there's a great chance that no one's gonna answer, SO is not a site for writing code for others

Comment: I search a lot Lukasz, but I don't know how I can do that. That's the problem.

Comment: Small hint: store the previous timestamp in a variable, when the next message is sent compare the previous datetime with the current one, if it's bigger than 5 minutes add the reaction and reset the variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Code

```
last_used = 0
cooldown = 300
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global last_used
    if message.content == "react to me":
        if time.time() > last_used+cooldown:
            await message.add_reaction("")
            last_used = time.time()
        else:
            await message.channel.send("You are on a cooldown!")
```

### Importing

We import the `time` module (this is built into python so no need to `pip install` it) so we can track the current time.

### Variables

the `last_used` variable is when the "react to me" message was last used. We can default it to 0 for the first usage.

The `cooldown` variable is the cooldown of the message in *seconds*.

Since this is not in a class, we have to `global` the `last_used` variable. We don't `global` the `cooldown` variable because we don't update it.

### Reacting

We first check if the message content is equal to "react to me". If it is, then we do some quick math. If the current time (we use `time.time()` to get the time) is later than the `last_used+cooldown` (this checks if the cooldown timer is up), then we react, and set the `last_used` equal to the current time.

### Error Handler

If this is not the case, we throw an error saying that the "cooldown timer is not up yet!".

#### Edit

This variable will be used for all of your users, so if you want to expand to multiple servers, I suggest that you create a database for all of the users `last_used` variable.